# Tomcat7 on Windows7 does not execute "setenv.bat"

Tags: windows-7, tomcat7, setenv

According to the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) the script %CATALINA_BASE%\bin/setenv.bat (if it exists) is on start automatically executed. Because I didn't see any result I added a "echo .. > ". But there is no message written so I'm pretty sure the script is not executed. I have added %CATALINA_BASE% to my Windows-environment variables - but this doesn't help either. Any idea out there about a possible cause for this behaviour?
Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

Some installations of tomcat use tomcat.conf to set JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that your default port for Tomcat (80/8080/8000) is not used by any other application....
I have faced the same issue but I solved by changing port number.

**Your Problem will be solved only if it's port number problem.**

Steps of changing the Tomcat Port

1) Locate server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder}\ conf \

2) Find following similar statement

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

OR

```
  <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

3) About Tomcat’s server.xml file cites it’s runs on port 8080. Change the Connector port=”8080″ port to any other port number.

For example

```
<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Above statement instruct Tomcat server runs on port 8181.

4) Edit and save the server.xml file. Restart Tomcat.

Done

This is my frnd's [Blog](http://akhil-mca.blogspot.in/2013/12/configure-apache-tomcat-for-jsp-gtu-wtad.html)...Follow this Step....For Installation

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the Tomcat is working fine with port 8080. It's not a new installion; I just want to replace logging by JULI by logging by SLFJ4/LOGBACK. Therefore I need to set the CLASSPATH. Currently I'm setting the CLASSPATH in the "Monitor Tomcat"-Service, but I would prefer the approach with the "setenv.bat"-file. And it should work anyway. 
btw: I tried your hint but it didn't solve it.I expected this; I can't see what the Connector-setting has to deal with ths command-issuing.

Comment: Sorry , It was not helpful to you....Even I expected this..coz May be chances of Different Problem...But as I sad Earlier I had same Problem , but for me I have tried by changing Port Number...